# php-amqplib non blocking example throws warnings

Tags: php-amqplib

I'm trying to use the videlalvaro/php-amqplib library for AMQP communication but can't seem to get the non-blocking version to work. Running demo/amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php just continually shows the following error message:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_select(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in RabbitMQ/test/amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php on line 86
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() RabbitMQ/test/amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php:0
PHP   2. stream_select(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*, *uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) RabbitMQ/test/amqp_consumer_non_blocking.php:86
```

Suppressing this message with the @ symbol quietens the error, but I still can't get it to show anything.

I *assume* I'm sending it a message correctly: I'm using the web interface and just publishing a message directly to the queue but like I say, I don't get anything in my non-blocking loop.

Doing the same process with the blocking demo (demo/amqp_consumer.php) works as expected.

Has anyone else had these sorts of problems or can they direct me to some possible solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you actually open a connection? Also, what version of the library are you using?

Comment: @old_sound: the connection seems fine and with it running in debug it does sit apparently waiting for a new frame. This was in v2.4.1. Over the weekend, though, I noticed that some changes had been merged into master at the end of last week and so those changes appear to have fixed the issue. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: same problem here. Can you tell me which version you are using ?

Comment: @Florian: I was working from the latest commit on master. At the time, that commit was 584a5ef0697abf7ac56c873736e62d5334eac44b if that helps?